# "Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context" in ternary operation

Tags: swift, enums, ternary-operator

I am trying to pass an enum to a function that does an operation on that enum's arguments. I receive this error:

`Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context`

The same error happens in an equivalent if clause, so it's not the ternary operator itself that causes the problem.

```
enum auto {
        case pkw (SerialNumber: String, Axles: Int, Weight: Float)
        case lkw (SerialNumber: String, Axles: Int, Weight: Float)
}

func checkIntegrity(car: auto) -> Bool {
        switch car {
        case .pkw:
            if (checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: .pkw.SerialNumber.rawValue)
                && checkWeight(weight: .pkw.Weight.rawValue)) { // Error here, "&&" is underlined
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            break;
        case .lkw:
            return (checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: .lkw.SerialNumber.rawValue)
                && checkWeight(weight: .lkw.Weight.rawValue)) ? true : false; // same error here, "&&" is underlined
            break;
        default:
            return false
}
```

The other functions that are called just return a Bool:

```
func checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: String) -> Bool {
        return serialNumber.contains("ABABWA") // changed after a hint in the comments
}

func checkWeight(weight: Float) -> Bool {
        return (weight < 2)
}
```

I am suspecting something wrong with the enum and how I use them, but I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: Constructions like `condition ? true : false` and `condition ? false : true` make no sense. Just do `condition` and `!condition` instead. Type of `condition` is `Bool` already, just use it directly.

Comment: You're right, that's kind of embarrassing! Thanks, I changed it.

Comment: Also, Swift `switch` case break by default. If you need a fallthrough, you have to explicitly mention that.

Comment: Also have a look at the Swift naming conventions. Types are uppercase, (e.g. `enum Auto`), everything else is lower case (e.g. `case pkw (serialNumber: String, axles: Int, weight: Float)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is misleading. You want to check the associated values
of an enumeration value, therefore you must bind those in the case pattern:

```
func checkIntegrity(car: auto) -> Bool {
    switch car {
    case let .pkw(serialNumber, _, weight):
        if checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: serialNumber)
            && checkWeight(weight: weight) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        break;
    case let .lkw(serialNumber, _, weight):
        return (checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: serialNumber)
            && checkWeight(weight: weight)) ? true : false;
        break;
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This can be simplified to

```
func checkIntegrity(car: auto) -> Bool {
    switch car {
    case let .pkw(serialNumber, _, weight),
         let .lkw(serialNumber, _, weight):
        return checkSerialNumber(serialNumber: serialNumber) && checkWeight(weight: weight)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the error. However, I do not really understand the `case let` part. I am doing a switch case over newly created enum instances? Is a switch case even necessary in this case? I must confess that I am a bit confused about this.

Comment: @mneumann: Have a look at [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) in the Swift book. In particular the “Associated Values” section, and the *“The different barcode types can be checked using a switch statement, as before. This time, however, the associated values can be extracted as part of the switch statement. ...”* part.